# Compare two array and print same value in php. Array data from database

Tags: php, arrays, database

I want to print same value in php . These value are coming from sql table.

When I run my code it shows **Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\wamp\www\programs\havingpassport_table.php on line 69**

What is the problem here. Please tell me
Here is my code `

```
<?php


$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","dat_database");



$havepassport='';

$get_emp_id='';

$get_cmp_emp_id='';



$sqlcmp="SELECT EMP_ID from emp_hei WHERE teamleader_id='MMUM253'"; 

$result_cmp = $conn -> query($sqlcmp);

while ($row_cmp = $result_cmp -> fetch_assoc()) {

$get_emp_id = $row_cmp['EMP_ID'];
 //echo $get_emp_id .'<br>';

}


echo '<br>';
$sql_cmp_emp="SELECT EMP_ID from emp_perdetails "; 

$result_cmp_emp = $conn -> query($sql_cmp_emp);

while ($row_cmp_emp = $result_cmp_emp -> fetch_assoc()) {

$get_cmp_emp_id = $row_cmp['EMP_ID'];

  //echo $get_cmp_emp_id .'<br>';
}



$result = array_intersect($get_emp_id, $get_cmp_emp_id);
print_r($result);
?>
```

`

Comment: Within while loops `$get_emp_id` must be `$get_emp_id[]` and `$get_cmp_emp_id` must be `$get_cmp_emp_id[]`. And afterwards check using `print_r` what is the output

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","dat_database");

$havepassport='';

$get_emp_id=array();

$get_cmp_emp_id=array();


$sqlcmp="SELECT EMP_ID from emp_hei WHERE teamleader_id='MMUM253'"; 

$result_cmp = $conn -> query($sqlcmp);

while ($row_cmp = $result_cmp -> fetch_assoc()) 
{

$get_emp_id[] = $row_cmp['EMP_ID'];

//echo $get_emp_id .'<br>';

}

echo '<br>';

$sql_cmp_emp="SELECT EMP_ID from emp_perdetails "; 

$result_cmp_emp = $conn -> query($sql_cmp_emp);

while ($row_cmp_emp = $result_cmp_emp -> fetch_assoc()) 
{

$get_cmp_emp_id[] = $row_cmp['EMP_ID'];

//echo $get_cmp_emp_id .'<br>';

}
$result = array_intersect($get_emp_id, $get_cmp_emp_id);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not saving the "to-be-arrays" as array. Try these codes

```
<?php
//connecting to the database
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","dat_database");

$havepassport='';

//output arrays
$get_emp_id     = [];
$get_cmp_emp_id = [];

//first query to create the $get_emp_id array
$sqlcmp     = "SELECT EMP_ID FROM emp_hei WHERE teamleader_id='MMUM253'"; 
$result_cmp = $conn->query($sqlcmp);

//fetching the EMP_ID into the array
while ($row_cmp = $result_cmp->fetch_assoc()) {
    $get_emp_id[] = $row_cmp['EMP_ID'];
}

//second query to create the $get_cmp_emp_id array
$sql_cmp_emp    ="SELECT EMP_ID FROM emp_perdetails";
$result_cmp_emp = $conn->query($sql_cmp_emp);

while ($row_cmp_emp = $result_cmp_emp->fetch_assoc()) {
    $get_cmp_emp_id[] = $row_cmp['EMP_ID'];
}

//generating the intersect results
$result = array_intersect($get_emp_id, $get_cmp_emp_id);

print_r($result);
?>
```

If it doesn't produce any results try outputting the results of each query whether any results were returned.